# Is a smart pointer (unique pointer) ALWAYS preferable to normal pointer?

Tags: c++

Smart pointers get automatically deallocated (deleted) when they go out of scope. 
Is there any such case wherein the smart/unique pointer gets deleted when we still want it to be available?

In other words, when should we use which pointer or can we use the unique pointer at all times?

Comment: I don't think one or the other fits all requirements.

Comment: This question appears entirely too broad, since I envision in detail writing at least one fat book about the topics. It's an ungood question. Can you pare it down to something more limited please.

Comment: [Worth the read](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3840.pdf).

Comment: `shared_ptr` does not get *automatically* deallocated.

Comment: This question has been discussed hundreds of times on SO. Personally, I don't think that the C++ community as a whole has reached any final conclusion yet. These features are quite new; we lack *experience* with them, especially in large projects whose codebases must be maintained for decades.

Comment: @Alf: Well, instead of judging people's questions, why don't you contribute towards the answer. The question is clear enough: Is there any case where normal pointers are preferable to unique pointers?

Comment: @AnonymousAndy every one of us **has to** judge your question.  That comment **does** contribute.  He made a helpful suggestion that you don't seem to be noticing.

Comment: @AnonymousAndy: The question you have in that comment, " Is there any case where normal pointers are preferable to unique pointers?", is answerable. If that is the intended question, can you update the, hm, SO question?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the *intended* question is really

> **”** Is there any case where normal pointers are preferable to unique pointers?

(as indicated by [a comment by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28486011/is-a-smart-pointer-unique-pointer-always-preferable-to-normal-pointer#comment45294004_28486011)), the answer is a clear **yes**.

A `std::unique_ptr` has unique ownership of an object.

Where you don't want ownership, but just observing and accessing an object, a raw pointer – or a functionally equivalent abstraction – is needed to avoid engaging in automated destructive behavior.

These are the most common uses of object pointers. Outputting a string literal you're already using such a pointer, namely a pointer to (the first item of) a character array. Declare the arguments of `main` and you have such a pointer again. They're just about everywhere. The operative word is perhaps “ubiquitous”, so common that one just don't notice them.

Answer (score 1):

An important principle of C++ programing is [Resource Acquisition Is Initialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) which achieves an important property of automatic cleanup of resources. This is particularly important for making C++ code exception-safe. You are far less likely to forget to clean up, and the C++ code you write is the same whether or not you *actually* use C++ exception handling.

A smart-pointer is a way to implement RAII in C++.

The C++11 standard `std::unique_ptr` is for something that is only ever *owned* by a single entity. When that entity is destroyed, the thing it owns should be cleaned up immediately.

`std::shared_ptr` is for something that has shared ownership between a number of entities, and the only time it should actually get deleted is when all references to it are gone. This is specifically where you don't actually know for sure which entity will be the 'last one standing'.

For Microsoft platforms when using COM objects, you should use `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<T>`. For WinRT programming with the C++/CX language extensions, the `T^` is the same thing.

All such references are 'strong' references which have guarantees about ownership. You can also have 'weak' references to the same resource, which in the case of a `std::unique_ptr` or `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<T>` is just a raw pointer. Weak references allow you to reference the object, but makes *no* claim about the ownership status of that object.

Raw pointers are therefore ideal for passing to functions as parameters that are going to execute sequentially (as opposed to asynchronously), calling legacy functions, etc. They all work perfectly fine as long as you make the guarantee that the 'strongly owning' objects can't be destroyed while someone is using a weak reference to the same thing.

In practice this means that you probably want to use smart-pointers in your class private data members to keep a hold of resources you created and want to exist for the life of the class, but you can and should use raw pointers as weak references for functions that need only temporary use of a resource.

You *can* of course pass smart-pointers as parameters, but you want to do as const ref:

```
void function(const std::unique_ptr<T>& data);
```

but it's probably easier and more convenient to use (as well as be able to more easily interface with other code that might not be using the same smart-pointers):

```
void function(T* data);
```

Now if you are actually going to return a fresh object or take ownership, then it would make more sense to use something like:

```
std::unique_ptr<T> function();

void function(std::unique_ptr<T>& data);
```

See [Smart Pointers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh279674.aspx), [ComPtr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br244983.aspx), and [Dual-use Coding Techniques for Games](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/09/17/dual-use-coding-techniques-for-games.aspx).

Comment: Isn't WRL a store app thing only? In them old days we used WTL (based on ATL) for dekstop programs.

Comment: WRL is a C++ template library, and you can use ``Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr`` in any C++ program. It's better than ATL's ``CComPtr`` because (a) ATL isn't in the Express editions, and (b) it doesn't have any dependencies on a REDIST DLL. The *rest* of WRL is for working with WinRT APIs, and some of them actually do work for Win32 desktop apps...

Answer (score 0):

You are conflating smart pointer with `unique_ptr`. When `shared_ptr` style management is required, clearly `unique_ptr` will not work, so you cannot say that it is "ALWAYS" preferable to a normal pointer. A normal pointer would at least allow shared access, although the management of that would be harder.

Comment: *"A normal pointer would at least allow shared access"* This is what I've been trying to explain in my answer.

Comment: @YassineHoussni Your question doesn't discuss shared access as there is only 1 pointer to each object in the array. You could use an array of `unique_ptr` and your code would still work. Indeed, that would be preferable.

Comment: Yes I understand now, my lack of C++ knowledge and my overruling knowledge of C made me think of that answer. Thanks for clearing that up for me.